# How to insert an array to a node js web service through angular js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to insert an array of data to a node js web service. The code looks like this.

```
$scope.addList = function(task,subtask){
         subtask.checked= !(subtask.checked);
       var data = {
       "taskId": task._id,
       "subTaskName": subtask.subTaskName,
     };     
        if(subtask.checked){

          angular.forEach(data, function(value,key){
            this.push(key + ': ' + value);
          },selectedMap); 

        }
        else{
          delete selectedMap;
        }
      }
```

If I print the selectedMap in console, I am getting array like this.

```
tasks:  {
0: "taskId: 1"
1: "subTaskName: SOW Updation"
2: "taskId: 1"
3: "subTaskName: Estimation - High Level"
4: "taskId: 2"
5: "subTaskName: Feasibility Study"
}
```

But I need to get like this to insert into DB

```
subTasks: [{
"task_id": 1,
"subTaskName": "Requirements Analysis"
},
{
"subTaskName": "Feasibility Study",
"task_id": 2
},
{
"subTaskName": "Requirement Elicitation",
"task_id": 3
},
{
"subTaskName": "Requirements Understanding",
"task_id": 4
},
{
"subTaskName": "Requirement Documentation",
"task_id": 5
}]
```

can anybody please help me to do this..?

Comment: just use `this.push(data)` - `data` has already the target format??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding key value in array instead of adding object.

Based on your output, `selectedMap` is not defined properly. It should be
`selectedMap = [];` instead of `selectedMap = {};` wherever you defined in your code.

Try this:

```
$scope.addList = function(task,subtask){
  subtask.checked= !(subtask.checked);
  var data = {
    "task_id": task._id,  // Updated key name based on your required output
    "subTaskName": subtask.subTaskName,
  };
  if(subtask.checked){
    selectedMap.push(data); // Add data object in array instead of key value pair    
  } else {
    selectedMap = selectedMap.filter(function(obj) {
          return (obj.task_id !== data.task_id && obj.subTaskName !== data.subTaskName);
    });
}
```

Comment: The push function is working very fine for me. But when I tried unchecking , the pop function is not working properly. It is removing the last checked data instead of unchecked one. Can you help me pls

Comment: Because when you unchecked item, if condition false and else will called which delete `selectedMap` variable so remove else code and then it should work fine...I hope this help you

Comment: If I remove else block, then the unchecked data is also getting pushed.

Comment: No, data push only if condition is true and if condition check that subtask is checked or not..Just give a try and then reply...

Comment: It will push the items which I check. But if I check an item , and again if I uncheck it, that is also added to the db

Comment: please add a jsfiddle link so that I can look your working code

Comment: We cant run the code in jsfiddle. It requires my company network. I have removed the else block. So, condition is there for item is checked. But if it is unchecked we have to remove the unchecked item

Comment: Now it removing all the data. It is giving me an empty array

Comment: I think that is because of `subtask.checked= !(subtask.checked);`. Why you have put this link in function? Can you explain? Try code by commenting this line...